# Check existence of an entry in C pre-processor list

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, x-macros

Is it possible to check for the existence of an entry in a list defined by X-macro?  Given the example code below, I'd like the `#if defined(GEORGE)` condition to be true.

EDIT: without doing an explicit `#define GEORGE`, of course.  I am hoping to have a way to check an entry in the list (in the pre-processor) and I only want to do the declaration in the list.  It is likely not possible but thought I ask.

Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NAMES \
X( JOHN, "John Adams" ) \
X( GEORGE, "George Washington" ) \
X( ABRAHAM, "Abraham Lincoln ")

#define X(_id, _name)    _id,
typedef enum {
    NAMES
} names_e;
#undef X

typedef struct {
    char *name;
} names_t;

#define X(_id, _name)    [_id] = { .name = _name },
static names_t const names[] = {
    NAMES
};
#undef X

int main(void) {
    int i;

    for (i=0; i < sizeof(names)/sizeof(names[0]); i++) {
        printf("%s\n", names[i].name);
    }

    printf("names[ABRAHAM] = %s\n", names[ABRAHAM].name);

#if defined(GEORGE)
    printf("names[GEORGE] = %s\n", names[GEORGE].name);
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
John Adams
George Washington
Abraham Lincoln 
names[ABRAHAM] = Abraham Lincoln
```

Comment: No, this is not possible. The C preprocessor doesn't know anything about arrays. You're not defining anything named `GEORGE` in the preprocessor, you're just using that macro to expand to enum and array initializations that will be processed by a later phase of the compiler.

Comment: `#if defined(GEORGE)` will be true iff you `#define GEORGE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use a preprocessor pattern matcher.  The concept simply requires a `SECOND` macro with indirection; `GLUE` is nice to shove arbitrary prefixes on:

```
#define GLUE(A,B) GLUE_I(A,B)
#define GLUE_I(A,B) A##B

#define SECOND(...) SECOND_I(__VA_ARGS__,,)
#define SECOND_I(A,B,...) B
```

...and for an X macro "column" that contains only "pseudo-identifiers":

```
#define NAMES \
X( JOHN, "John Adams" ) \
X( GEORGE, "George Washington" ) \
X( ABRAHAM, "Abraham Lincoln ")
```

...you could do this:

```
#define X(ID_, NAME_) SECOND(GLUE(SEARCH_FOR_,ID_),+0)
#define SEARCH_FOR_GEORGE ,+1
#if NAMES
printf("names[GEORGE] = %s\n", names[GEORGE].name);
#endif
#undef SEARCH_FOR_GEORGE
#define SEARCH_FOR_THOMAS ,+1
#if NAMES
#error Dewey wins!
#endif
#undef SEARCH_FOR_THOMAS
#undef X
```

This works because `SECOND` *indirectly* expands to the second argument; so `SECOND(GLUE(SEARCH_FOR,ID_),+0)` by default will expand to `+0`; and any chain of `+0` is a valid false expression.  But because the expansion's indirect, and the first argument is that pasted token, then if you define the pasted token `SEARCH_FOR_GEORGE` to itself expand with a comma in it, the expression after the comma becomes the new second argument.  (Ask me if you need this to work on Microsoft VS preprocessors; that requires a tiny tweak).

Comment: Thank you.  This addresses my question completely.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't write macros inside a macro body, so it is going to be tricky to manage it with the outline you've got (I don't see a way to achieve it).

You can only test macros in the preprocessor (not the names of enumeration elements), and you can't write macros via the preprocessor (a `#define` can't usefully generate a new `#define` based on its arguments), so you have to do some grunt-work.

If you define

```
#define P_JOHN 0
#define P_GEORGE 1
#define P_ABRAHAM 2
```

then you could use:

```
#define NAMES \
X( JOHN, "John Adams" ) \
X( GEORGE, "George Washington" ) \
X( ABRAHAM, "Abraham Lincoln ")

#define X(_id, _name)    _id = P_ ## _id,   // Crucial change
typedef enum
{
    NAMES
} names_e;
#undef X

typedef struct
{
    char *name;
} names_t;

#define X(_id, _name)    [_id] = { .name = _name },
static names_t const names[] =
{
    NAMES
};
#undef X

int main(void) {
    int i;

    for (i=0; i < sizeof(names)/sizeof(names[0]); i++) {
        printf("%s\n", names[i].name);
    }

    printf("names[ABRAHAM] = %s\n", names[ABRAHAM].name);

#if defined(P_GEORGE)        // Crucial change
    printf("names[GEORGE] = %s\n", names[GEORGE].name);
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the onus is on you to ensure that the `P_*` names have unique numbers (and I'm not sure what you're going to do about George H W Bush and George W Bush — there seems to be a conflict with George Washington there).

Example output:

```
John Adams
George Washington
Abraham Lincoln 
names[ABRAHAM] = Abraham Lincoln 
names[GEORGE] = George Washington
```